# omdbapi.com REST api JSON into Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, angular5

Hey guys I am trying to get the data from a moviedatabase api to show up in my Angular 5 app. I managed to get it to post in the console with JSONstringify, but as soon as i try to ngFor loop through the data it either gives me nothing at all or [object, Object].

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IMovie } from './movie';

@Injectable()
export class MoviesService {

private _url: string = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=*took-that-out*";
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
  return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this._url);
}
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MoviesService } from './../movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-featured',
  templateUrl: './featured.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./featured.component.css']
})

export class FeaturedComponent implements OnInit{

  public movies = [];

  constructor(private _moviesService: MoviesService){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._moviesService.getMovies()
      .subscribe(data => this.movies = data);
  }

 }
```

the interface

```
export interface IMovie{
title: string;
year: string;
rated: string;
released: string;
runtime: string;
genre: string;
director: string;
writer: string;
actors: string;
plot: string;
language: string;
country: string;
awards: string;
poster: string;
//ratings: Ratings;
metascore: string;
imdbrating: string;
imdbVotes: string;
imdbid: string;
type: string;
dvd: string;
boxOffice: string;
production: string;
website: string;
response: string;
}
```

and the html

```
<h2>list of movies</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let movie of movies">
  <li>{{movie.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Edit: added the JSON from the api below

```
{
  "Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
  "Year": "2017",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "05 May 2017",
  "Runtime": "136 min",
  "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
  "Director": "James Gunn",
  "Writer": "James Gunn, Dan Abnett (based on the Marvel comics by), Andy     Lanning (based on the Marvel comics by), Steve Englehart (Star-lord created by), Steve Gan (Star-lord created by), Jim Starlin (Gamora and Drax created by), Stan Lee (Groot created by), Larry Lieber (Groot created by), Jack Kirby (Groot created by), Bill Mantlo (Rocket Raccoon created by), Keith Giffen (Rocket Raccoon created by), Steve Gerber (Howard the Duck created by), Val Mayerik (Howard the Duck created by)",
  "Actors": "Chris Pratt, Zoe Saldana, Dave Bautista, Vin Diesel",
  "Plot": "The Guardians must fight to keep their newfound family together as they unravel the mystery of Peter Quill's true parentage.",
  "Language": "English",
  "Country": "USA, New Zealand, Canada",
  "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 7 wins & 26 nominations.",
  "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg2MzI1MTg3OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTU3NDA2MTI@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings": [
    {
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "7.7/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "83%"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Metacritic",
      "Value": "67/100"
    }
  ],
  "Metascore": "67",
  "imdbRating": "7.7",
  "imdbVotes": "336,851",
  "imdbID": "tt3896198",
  "Type": "movie",
  "DVD": "22 Aug 2017",
  "BoxOffice": "$389,804,217",
  "Production": "Walt Disney Pictures",
  "Website": "https://marvel.com/guardians",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

Comment: What is the response from API 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=*took-that-out*'? Check its JSON data format. Make sure 'data' is an array.

Comment: I added the api output. Looks like a simple array to me, but when i try to log it to console i got undefined.

Comment: That is a single object, not an array. { } is an object, [ ] is an array.

Comment: Do i have to stringify it or read out the object differently?

Comment: Your 'movies' property is expecting an array. However, returned JSON from response is an object. You need to change it to 'movie: IMovie', in template, use '{{movie.title}}' to access the data. By the way, the response is using capitalized property name, be sure that it will be mapped automatically to your interface definition which is using camel case.

Comment: Works! Alright, i changed movies to movie and had to in the subscribe params. Then took away the array property AND like you said had to use {{movie.Title}} with a capital! why doesn't it conform to my lowercase interface?

Comment: JSON is Javascript Object Notation and Javascript is case sensitive language. That is why you need to pay attention to it for object mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `[Object Object]` is because OMDb API returns an Object with three properties:  { `Response`, `Search`, `totalResults` }.

In order to skip that error you only have to access the Search property containing your `movies[]` and loop trough it using `*ngFor`.

Code example:

```
<ul *ngIf="responseData">
   <li *ngFor="let movie of responseData.Search">{{ movie.Title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Please remember to check your {{ data binding }} and make sure your property matches the response obj property -- they are capitalized.